# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel-5

why I am getting this error. I can't understand.

My method
................

```
$admins = Admin::where('permission' , 8)
                        ->get();

 $arr = [];


    foreach ($admins as $admin) {

        $date1 = now();

        $date    =  $date1->format('Y-m-d');

        $data = count(Tradelicence::where('admin_id' , $admin['id'])
                            ->where('created_at' , 'like', "%$date%")
                            ->get());

        $name = $admin['name'];

        array_push($arr, [ $name => $data]);
    }

    $arrays = json_encode($arr);
```

In blade file
...............

```
@foreach($arrays as $key => $value)
          <tr>

            <td>{{ $key }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value }</td>

          </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `json_encode` returns __string__.

Comment: Why do you need the `json_encode()`? Pass the array only.

Comment: you need to send `$arr` to your `blade view` directly. then use `$arr` instead of `$array`

Comment: without JSON encode i am getting this error 

htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be that Admin::where('permission' , 8)->get(); returns something else than an array, probably null.
You could catch that with following after the $admins = Admin::where('permission' , 8)->get();

```
if(false === is_array($admins) {
    $admins = [];
}
```

Also you have an error for your blade template, your array looks like:

```
[
     ['key' => 'value']
]
```

Instead of array_push($arr, [ $name => $data]);

You should only do:

```
$arr[$name] = $data;
```